# How to import the hundreds of API Demos in the android SDK when so many are called MainActivity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I wanted to run the various samples to learn android better but was dismayed to find so many projects have duplicate project names - all imaginatively called MainActivity!

> C:\Users\me\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\samples\android-19

I am trying to use Eclipse ADT plugin and File|Import|Existing Android Code.

Is there a simple and clever way to do it rather than tediously one by one to change the project name to avoid conflicts?

Comment: If you're not using "gradle", you may have better luck with the projects in the "legacy" directory.

Comment: @fadden not using gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different suggestions (based on my prior experience of Eclipse, which might be outdated now because I only use Android Studio):

- Import all of the projects at the same time from the root of the parent folder of the samples. This usually worked for me when I had to import large numbers of project samples from some Android book (just turn off automatic rebuild before you do that).
- Do not use the import functionality for the official samples. The new project wizard has its own way of generating sample projects.
- Try out ApiDemos on your actual device before trying it out on Eclipse. A couple of people have repackaged the ApiDemos and placed them on Google Play. Install the one that has the highest ratings. Here is the one for [api level 17 for instance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.axet.android.apis) (thought, I don't know if there is a good one for api level 19 yet).
- Try out the app called [DevAppsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect&hl=en) (which is an API Demos created by the community, and which in my opinion is far better than the official API Demos)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Will try them all out. Have installed API 17 demos.